# On the Reputation Tab label migrated questions as Migrated instead of Deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

While looking through the history on my reputation tag, I noticed questions that have been migrated to other SE sites are labeled as deleted.

For example 
[How to deal with the developers refusing to use certain technologies or tools?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84332/how-to-deal-with-the-developers-refusing-to-use-certain-technologies-or-tools)
was migrated to Programmers SE and shows up like this in my reputation history:

[image: Reputation History shows migrated question as deleted]

I could see it being helpful to change deleted to migrated, and even make the question title a link to the question on the migrated site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This now happens, we'll show "migrated" and a tooltip of "post was migrated away" when rendering these.  Additionally, if you can see these items (only on your own profile, since they are still deleted posts), we'll *always* link them...since either you can see it, or would be redirected to the post's migration target.